# getJSON returns nothing on screen

Tags: android, json

I am having an issue with with getJSON and onCellLocationChanged. I am trying to make call an PHP from onCellLocationChanged, but I dont receive any response. What can be a reason?

This is mine onCellLocationChanged:

```
public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation lokacija) {
        super.onCellLocationChanged(lokacija);
        location = (GsmCellLocation) Phone.getCellLocation();
        textCellId.setText(String.valueOf(location.getCid() % 65536));
        textCellLac.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLac()));
        getJSON(JSON_URL);
    }
```

And this is getJSON:

```
private void getJSON(String url) {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait...",null,true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String uri = params[0];

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        sb.append(json+"\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    return null;
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                textCellName.setText(s);
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute(url);
    }
```

PHP is working fine, it returns something like this,

```
{
    "result": [{
        "id": "1",
        "username": "test",
        "password": "test"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "username": "test2",
        "password": "test2"
    }]
}
```

TextView that should show result:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/stringCellName"
    android:id="@+id/textCellName"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:maxLines="20"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Here is a log. There are no exceptions

```
04-11 10:05:11.745 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication themeResourceId=2131230846
04-11 10:05:11.806 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
04-11 10:05:11.831 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/PhoneWindowEx: [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xfff5f5f5
04-11 10:05:11.831 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x fff5f5f5
04-11 10:05:12.089 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/LgDataFeature: LgDataFeature() Constructor: none
04-11 10:05:12.089 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/LgDataFeature: LgDataFeature() Constructor Done, null
04-11 10:05:12.148 22118-22430/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
04-11 10:05:12.150 22118-22430/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                                    Build Date: 12/12/14 금
                                                                                    Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.031_20141212_01821442
                                                                                    Remote Branch: 
                                                                                    Local Patches: 
                                                                                    Reconstruct Branch: 
04-11 10:05:12.153 22118-22430/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-11 10:05:12.201 22118-22430/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-11 10:05:12.212 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/Atlas: Validating map...
04-11 10:05:12.258 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
04-11 10:05:12.261 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/PhoneWindowEx: [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xfff5f5f5
04-11 10:05:12.261 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x fff5f5f5
04-11 10:05:12.693 22118-22118/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3af55dc4 time:1819759669
```

Here is a log with requested changes:

```
04-11 10:41:55.585 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-11 10:41:59.507 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/ContextHelper: convertTheme. context->name=com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication themeResourceId=2131230846
04-11 10:41:59.570 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
04-11 10:41:59.611 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/PhoneWindowEx: [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xfff5f5f5
04-11 10:41:59.611 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x fff5f5f5
04-11 10:41:59.764 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/LgDataFeature: LgDataFeature() Constructor: none
04-11 10:41:59.764 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/LgDataFeature: LgDataFeature() Constructor Done, null
04-11 10:41:59.794 25702-26162/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
04-11 10:41:59.797 25702-26162/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
                                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                                                    Build Date: 12/12/14 금
                                                                                    Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.031_20141212_01821442
                                                                                    Remote Branch: 
                                                                                    Local Patches: 
                                                                                    Reconstruct Branch: 
04-11 10:41:59.803 25702-26162/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-11 10:41:59.866 25702-26162/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-11 10:41:59.881 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/Atlas: Validating map...
04-11 10:41:59.955 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/PhoneWindow: [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
04-11 10:41:59.957 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication D/PhoneWindowEx: [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xfff5f5f5
04-11 10:41:59.957 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x fff5f5f5
04-11 10:41:59.988 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/System.out: loading
04-11 10:41:59.988 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/System.out: http://neo.telenor.rs/telenorapp/fetchdata.php
04-11 10:42:00.273 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/System.out: null
04-11 10:42:00.291 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2ea15c75 time:92495663
04-11 10:42:00.299 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-11 10:42:07.290 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2ea15c75 time:92502662
04-11 10:42:25.317 25702-25702/com.zelenigrad.bsavkovic.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2ea15c75 time:92520689
```

Comment: Log the exception, in case you are getting one. Also, log the response.

Comment: textCellId and textCellLac, do they change when onCellLocationChanged happens? What is your url? is it uri or url string?

Comment: I added log. textCellLac and textCellId are working properly. My php url is:  private static final String JSON_URL = "http://xxxxxxx/fetchdata.php";

Comment: Where is your `textCellName` object?

Comment: Its defined in onCreate where I also defined textCellId and textCellLac.

Comment: Put System.out.println(JSON_URL) in onCellLocationChanged and put another system.out.println("loading") on onPreExecute() and finally system.out.println(s) on onPostExecute and share the results pls

Comment: I added a log. Can you help me how to format it properly?

Comment: I forgot to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> to Manifest. Now everything works fine.